# How to make the built-in LED blink with a frequency of 5 Hz using interrupts

Tags: arduino-uno, interrupt

The task is: after five clicks on OK, the built-in LED starts flashing with a frequency of 5Hz using an interrupt. After the eighth click on OK, the flashing (and glowing) should stop.Why is flashing not working

```
bool ledState = false;
volatile bool ledOn = true;

void setup(){
TCCR2A = 0;
  TCCR2B = 0;
  TIMSK2 = 0;
  TCNT2 = 0;
  OCR2A = 77;
  TCCR2B |= (1 << CS22) | (1 << CS21) | (1 << CS20);
  TIMSK2 |= (1 << OCIE2A);
 pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
}

void loop(){
 if(button5.buttonPressedCount >= 5 && button5.buttonPressedCount < 8){
    ledState = true;
  }

  if(button5.buttonPressedCount > 7){
    ledState = false;
  }
}

ISR(TIMER2_COMPA_vect){
  if(ledState){
  digitalWrite(13, ledOn);
  ledOn = !ledOn;
  }
}
```

Comment: Why `OCR2A = 77;`?

Comment: The value for obtaining a frequency of 5 Hz with a divider of 1024

Comment: Could you please explain, within the question, how you go from “f = 5 Hz” to `OCR2A = 77;`?

Comment: timer will run at a frequency of 16 MHz / 1024 = 15.625 kHz, so desired interrupt frequency = (77 + 1) * 15.625 kHz / 1024 = 5 Hz

Comment: This calculation is wrong.

Comment: then what should the values ​​be?

Comment: 15.625kHz / 5 Hz = 3125. So I would set OCR2A to 3125. A value of 77 would be about 203Hz

Comment: I set to 3125 if this correct signal: [link](https://imgur.com/a/N4wQMrl)

Comment: Could you use Timer 1 instead of Timer 2?

Comment: yes I can, then what values ​​should be set?

Answer (score 2):

On the Uno (ATmega328P microcontroller), timers 0 and 2 are 8-bit only:
they cannot count beyond 255. Timer 1, on the other hand, is 16-bits.
This is the most convenient timer for generating low frequencies.

Speaking of frequencies... One LED period involves two toggles (turn on,
then turn off). Thus, if you want the LED to blink at 5 Hz, the toggle
action should happen at 10 Hz. Given that the CPU is clocked at 16 MHz,
this means you have to toggle the LED every 1,600,000 CPU cycles.

If you set the prescaler to 1,024, you then you have to count
1,600,000/1,024 = 1,562.5 timer cycles. You cannot count a non-integer
number of cycles, but you probably do not care about such accuracy. If
you do care, set the prescaler to 256 and count 1,600,000/256 =
6,250 timer cycles by setting the compare match register to 6,249.

One last issue: keep in mind that, in normal counting mode, the timer
counts up to its maximum value (65,535, or 255 on an 8-bit timer) and
then restarts at zero. If you want it to count only up the value set in
the compare match register, you should choose the appropriate waveform
generation mode: the fast PWM mode that lets you control the TOP value
with OCR1A.

Comment: then it should look like this? `TCCR1A = 0;
TCCR1B = 0;
TIMSK1 = 0;
TCNT1 = 0;
OCR1A = 6249; // Set compare match value for prescaler 256
TCCR1B |= (1 << CS12); // Set prescaler to 256
TIMSK1 |= (1 << OCIE1A); // Enable interrupt on compare match A`

Comment: @GoodYork: Read the datasheet and see how to set the appropriate waveform generation mode.

Comment: like this: `TCCR1A = (1 << WGM11) | (1 << COM1A0);
  TCCR1B = (1 << WGM12) | (1 << WGM13) | (1 << CS12);
  TIMSK1 = (1 << OCIE1A);
  OCR1A = 6250;`